# Mock Event Listeners in Scala Test

Tags: scala, events, observer-pattern

I have a service that has a method which pushes events into an Observer. I'm now trying to come up with unit tests to test this service. I want to mock the behaviour and wait until I get the first two messages pushed into the Observer. Is there a way to do this? Currently, I can see that my tests pass but only if I place a break-point in my service method where the events are pushed into the service.

```
val propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener {
  override def propertyChange(evt: PropertyChangeEvent): Unit = {

    val dataItemOldValue = evt.getOldValue.asInstanceOf[DataItemValue]
    val dataItemNewValue = evt.getNewValue.asInstanceOf[DataItemValue]

    dataItemOldValue.getValue.asBoolean() shouldBe true
    dataItemNewValue.getValue.asBoolean() shouldBe true

    println(dataItemOldValue.getValue.getType)

    println(s"new Value ${evt.getNewValue}")
    println(evt.getOldValue)
  }
}
```